# The Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by the product topology coincides with the product of Borel $\sigma$-algebras: where did I get wrong?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, second-countable

Let $(\Omega_n, \tau_n)_n$ be a sequence of metrizable topological spaces. Let $\sigma (\tau_n)$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega_n$. Let $\Omega :=\prod_{n =1}^\infty \Omega_n$ and $\pi_n: \Omega \to \Omega_n$ be the canonical projection map. Let

- $\bigotimes_n \sigma (\tau_n)$ be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ such that all maps $\pi_n$'s are measurable.
- $\sigma (\bigotimes_n \tau_n)$ be the Borel $\sigma$ algebra on $\Omega$ that is generated by the product topology $\bigotimes_n \tau_n$ on $\Omega$.

It follows from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/248587/368425) answer that below theorem is false without the assumption that each $\tau_n$ is second-countable. However, I manage to "prove it" without this assumption.

> **False Theorem:** $\bigotimes_n \sigma (\tau_n) = \sigma (\bigotimes_n \tau_n)$.

Could you elaborate on where I made a mistake? Thank you so much!

**My attempt:** We have  $\bigotimes_n \tau_n$ [is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361778/show-that-the-countable-product-of-metric-spaces-is-metrizable) metrizable and [thus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_space#Examples_of_normal_spaces) perfectly normal. Hence $\sigma (\bigotimes_n \tau_n)$ [is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189567/prove-that-borel-sigma-field-on-rd-is-the-smallest-sigma-field-that-makes-all#comment437244_189567) the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ such that every continuous function whose domain is $\Omega$ is measurable. We have $\pi_n$ is continuous w.r.t. $\bigotimes_n \tau_n$. Hence $\pi_n$ is measurable w.r.t. $\sigma (\bigotimes_n \tau_n)$. It follows that
$$
\bigotimes_n \sigma (\tau_n) \subset \sigma (\bigotimes_n \tau_n).
$$

Let's prove the reverse, i.e.,
$$
\sigma (\bigotimes_n \tau_n) \subset \bigotimes_n \sigma (\tau_n).
$$

Let
$$
\mathcal C := \{\pi^{-1}_n(A_n) \mid n \in \mathbb N, A_n \in \sigma (\tau_n)\}.
$$

[Then](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1370091/definition-of-the-product-sigma-algebra) $\bigotimes_n \sigma (\tau_n) = \sigma (\mathcal C)$. So we want to prove
$$
\sigma (\bigotimes_n \tau_n) \subset \sigma (\mathcal C).
$$

Let
$$
\mathcal D := \{\pi^{-1}_n(A_n) \mid n \in \mathbb N, A_n \in \tau_n\}.
$$

Then $\bigotimes_n \tau_n$ is the topology on $\Omega$ generated by $\mathcal D$.  This also means that $\mathcal D$ is a subbase of $\bigotimes_n \tau_n$. This implies
$$
\sigma (\bigotimes_n \tau_n) = \sigma (\mathcal D) .
$$

The claim then follows trivially by the fact that $\mathcal D \subset \mathcal C$.

Comment: Do it first for the product of two measuable spaces so that $X=X_1\times X_2.$ The point is that in the second-countable case,  every open set $O$ in $X$ is a *countable* union of sets of the form $U\times V.$ This implies that $O\in \mathcal B(X_1)\times \mathcal B(X_2).$ [These answers and  discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4523260/proof-product-of-%cf%83-algebras-in-separable-metric-spaces/4523310#4523310) may help you.

Comment: I have also found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1415201/if-mathcalb-is-a-base-of-a-topology-space-leftx-tau-right-then-the-b) related thread...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the last step.  It is true that $\mathcal{D}$ is a subbase of $\bigotimes_n \tau_n$, but this does not imply they generate the same $\sigma$-algebra.  Indeed, every element of $\bigotimes_n \tau_n$ is a union of finite intersections of elements of $\mathcal{D}$.  These unions may not be countable, and so may not be in $\sigma(\mathcal{D})$.  (This is fixed by the second-countable assumption, which can be used to show that every open set is actually a *countable* union of finite intersections of elements of $\mathcal{D}$.)